# Ударение слова "кровь"

Tags: ударение

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать ударение на слове *кровь* в предложении: "Чист от крови".

Comment: @MaksimV2013, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Из словаря Резниченко:

Кровь - существительное акцентного класса А (ударение сохраняется на основе во всех формах).

Но есть исключения:

1) П.п.: о крОви (изъяснительное значение), но: в кровИ (обстоятельственное значение).

2) Фразеологизмы: дО крови и до крОви, клясться на кровИ, хороших кровЕй.

3)До кровИ - нарушение нормы, но встречается у поэтов.

Поэтому делаем вывод: чист от крОви: нет обстоятельственного значения, это не фразеологизм.

Comment: >клясться на кровИ

А что это означает? Объясните, пожалуйста, если не сложно.

Я это выражение слышал, пожалуй, только в песне "Ваше благородие, госпожа Удача" из фильма "Белое солнце пустыни".

Comment: Не возражаете, я отвечу?   
  
Вариантов кровной клятвы было несколько. 
Самый простой: слегка надрезался палец и капельуой крови как чернилами подписывался "клятвенный" документ.    
Но у Окуджавы скорее всего имеется в виду клятва верности: по капельке крови каждого из участников союза выдавливалось в бокал с вином, после чего каждый делал из него глоток. Все это действо могло сопровождаться дополнительным антуражем, но не обязательно.     
Были и другие варианты.      
   
(+)  
  
А может, это сделаем отдельным вопросом? Оно того стоит.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Можно и отдельным вопросом.

Comment: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/45962

Answer (score 0):

Выскажу крамольную мысль. 
В прямом значении ("несмотря на ранение, документы солдата остались чистыми от кр**о**ви") никаких причин переносить ударение не вижу.

В переносном же значении выражение "чист от крови" (не совершал убийства) производит впечатление фразеологизма, в котором так и хочется сказать "от кров**и**". Никаких аргументов в пользу этого привести не могу, считайте моей личной "фишкой".