# Клясться на кровИ

Tags: значение-слов

В теме ["Ударение слова "кровь"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/45887/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C) упоминалось выражение *"клясться на кровИ"*.

А что это означает? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Я это выражение слышал, пожалуй, только в песне "Ваше благородие, госпожа Удача" из фильма "Белое солнце пустыни".

Comment: В песне Верещагина "Перестаньте черти клясться на крови.."имеется ввиду кровной мести в странах бывшей российской империи. Это означает что черти это как сейчас принято называть "духи", "бармалеи" и тд. В данное время происходило сопротивление новой власти, а именно красной армии. Во время царского правления также были не согласные и на востоке это были отряды "басмачей". Басмачество это противостояние существующей власти со стороны Турции и в те времена было обычным явлением в тех местах. Зародилось в Турции и способствовало образованию мусульманского государства Туркистан на территории Туркм

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Переношу ответ из комментария к предыдущему и дополняю его*

Вообще обычай очень древний, восходит то ли ко временам Рима, то ли к викингам.
Вариантов кровной клятвы было несколько. Самый простой: слегка надрезался палец и капелькой крови как чернилами подписывался "клятвенный" документ.
Но у Окуджавы скорее всего имеется в виду клятва верности: по капельке крови каждого из участников союза выдавливалось в бокал с вином, после чего каждый делал из него глоток. Все это действо могло сопровождаться дополнительным антуражем, но не обязательно.
Были и другие варианты.
Среди подростков пятидесятых-шестидесятых (возможно и раньше) была популярна "клятва" в виде кровавого рукопожатия: ладонь правой руки надрезалась до крови, после чего "кореша" обменивались рукопожатием.
Иногда эта клятва проводилась с использованием икон. Ладонь (в этом случае обычно левая - для удобства) надрезалась и обращалась к иконе, после чего произносились слова клятвы.
Надо сказать, что христианство к подобному действу относилось крайне неодобрительно, считая его языческим, если не сатанинским. Часто проводилось тайно. Поэтому подобные обряды в разных источниках описываются очень по-разному, а достоверность их показа в книгах и фильмах весьма сомнительна.

Comment: Ответ @behemothus является исчерпывающим . Я его только чуточку дополню - применительно к строкам Б. Окуджавы : "перестаньте черти клясться на крови ..." . У медиумов известен способ вызывать духов и всякую нечисть с использованием чаши со свежей кровью (в частности , этот способ был  популярен у английских медиумов) . Черти , как и духи , собираются на запах крови у магического круга . Я знаю в Крыму одну деревенскую колдунью (реальную) . Она объяснила мне , что черти всё знают , но могут быть лживы . Т.е. ,  если " черти клянутся на крови" , они тем самым клятвенно убеждают им поверить .

Comment: Вы полагаете, что у Окуджавы имелись в виду черти в прямом смысле: с рогами и копытами? А не друзья-товарищи, которых лирический герой "ласково" называет чертями? Ну не знаю... Где Окуджава - и где мистика?!

Comment: (+) Посмотрел гуглом навскидку про этих чертей. Признаю, ваша версия встречается среди прочих. Но как-то малоубедительно.

Comment: @ behemothus  .  Я полагаю , что автор подразумевает чертей в прямом смысле . Это литературный прием : то ли метафора , то или как-то по другому называется , точно не знаю . А , чтобы оценить эту мою ремарку , как более , чем  "малоубедительную" , надо быть знакомым с магией хоть чуточку напрямую , а не через Гугл .

Comment: Вы думаете, Окуджава был знаком с магией? Простите, будучи знаком с его творчеством - (и в одностороннем порядке - вживую) никак не могу согласиться с вашей трактовкой. Он был человеком очень реалистичным и конкретным. Чертовщиной не интересовался. Впрочем, может в этом и есть гениальность, когда каждый понимает по-своему.

Comment: Но Окуджава ж был поэт-романтик . Таким всегда хоть немножечко свойственна мистика . Вот он и использовал мистический образ . Вл. Маяковский , вот , тоже был убеждённый реалист-материалист , а почитайте-ка его "Тамара и Демон" !

Comment: Фантазия ваша. Не был мистиком Окуджава. Да и Маяковского вы несколько своеобразно толкуете.

Answer (score 4):

Это просто: клятва, совершённая при ритуальном кровопускании, что подчёркивает её значимость. Наверняка много раз в кино видели, когда герой режет ладонь и клянётся сделать что-либо. Крови издревле присваивали магическое значение: она использовалась в разных обрядах, в том числе ей полагалось подписывать сделку с дьяволом. Использование крови как бы усиливало значимость и неотвратимость заключённых сделок, клятв и ритуалов.

Answer (score 0):

КровЬ - солёная. Соль - когда-то была большой ценностью. Особо дорогого гостя встречали хлебом и солью. Этот обычай - языческий. Та-да-да-дам-м. Но мы ведь не варвары какие, да? И вот появляется ритуал - инаугурации, рука ложится на книгу (предмет), произносится клятва. Ну а песне? Если нет под рукой сакральных предметов, соль можно добыть из...

Answer (score 0):

Всплыл этот вопрос. Добавлю. Есть ведь хорошо известная версия, которую я почему-то упустил пять лет назад, но которая сейчас выглядит приоритетной.
Она в корне отличается от всего ранее сказанного, поэтому оформляю отдельным ответом.

Очень возможно, что здесь вообще нет никого мистического действа, даже элемента такового. Для Окуджавы мистические мотивы - редкость, если вообще есть где-то...

Так вот и тут, "на крови" вполне может быть всего лишь местом, где произошло убийство (пролилась кровь). Помните "Спаса на крови"? Вот, возможно, тут тот же случай.
Помимо упомянутого соображения о несвойственности мистики для текстов Окуджавы, версия эта косвенно подтверждается упоминанием "смерти" в следующей строчке, превращая её в своеобразный рефрен.

Но главное, что хорошо в этой версии, - это правильное в этом случае ударение. В локативе (местном значении предложного падежа) у существительных третьего склонения происходит регулярное смещение ударения на флексию: (вывалялся) в шерст**и**, крепок в кост**и**, клялся на кров**и**.

Итак, по этой версии - клятва на крови - всего лишь клятва мщения, произнесенная на месте убийства родственника или, как, вероятно, в нашем случае, друга.